Where to ask questions about non-DNS-based country-based website/HTTP blocking?
I am personally interested in who and/or how website/HTTP blocking is done in the case of this question: How is my ISP blocking my DNS query if I'm using DoH (DNS-over-HTTPS)?
As I mentioned as comment, while DNS blocking is done as well, using DoH, clients do get the correct IP, and still cannot connect to/get unexpected/invalid responses from the correct/intended host.
It was closed as OOT, but I could not find a better fitting StackExchange site, looking through all of them. Does someone have a suggestion, where to ask it instead?
I did quite a lot of investigation with the user who asked it, and since we by times deal with network/internet related issues of users, it would be very helpful to know which actor is performing these blocks, and how it is technically done. That way we can better detect/help/inform about similar cases, and the matter in general raises security/privacy concerns, if the ISP or other actors on the route perform HTTPS inspection.

@MichaIng - It’s never too late to reword a question
